# Some video files in Android phone don't shown when connected to Ubuntu OS

Tags: android

when i connect my android phone into my Lenovo Idepad 310 Laptopp with new Ubuntu OS, i can not see some files into the owns drives, for example you could see here:

[image]

but in my Android phone i have :

[image]
[image]

***Update:***

and the permission of the target folder into my Ubuntu nautilus file manager don't detected like this:

[image]

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your videos are on SD card.

Comment: I'm guessing that either: You're not looking at the same folder on your phone & computer (maybe videos are on the SD card in the phone), _or_ your phone doesn't immediately make newly created files available over USB - my old phone did this, and I had to reboot it before files would show up on USB.

Comment: yes you are right, so excuse me  thanks @pilot6. do  i  delete this question or to past this as answer to accepted question?

Comment: You can write an answer. The question is not 100% about Ubuntu. But it may be useful for someone.

Comment: you mean: do i answer myself?

Answer (score 1):

According to [@Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6) comment :

> Your videos are on SD card. – [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6) 11 mins ago

I checked my Android phone an found @Pilot6 is right, So i answered my question by myself and the answer is :

> The videos are on SD card ...

Thanks.